# minidlna doesn't like hardlinks

Tags: linux, video, inotify, hardlink

I have a video files in:

```
/home/private/movies/video1.mkv
/home/private/movies/video2.mkv
/home/private/movies/video3.mkv
```

I have hardlinks to those mkv files in:

```
/home/minidlna/videos/video1.mkv
/home/minidlna/videos/video2.mkv
/home/minidlna/videos/video3.mkv
```

My minidlna share is:

```
 /home/minidlna
```

The video files show up on the minidlna cilent (my TV) after I do a full rescan of the minidlna share, however, they don't show up if I create new hardlinks with the inotify interval set really low.

The files **do** show up if they are **not** hardlinks.

My guess is that there seems to be a problem with minidlna and the way it processes the 'filesystem changes' using 'inotify'.  Perhaps a hardlink isn't necessary a 'change' to notify minidlna.

My video library is rather large and continually doing rescans seems very inefficient and takes a long time.  I would appreciate if someone can shed some light on this or have a workaround.

I'm running minidlna version 1.1.4

Answer (score 0):

It appears it is indeed [a problem with `minidlna`](http://sourceforge.net/p/minidlna/bugs/227/).

Depending on your use case, maybe you can create the new video file *in the minidlna directory* and make the one in your private movies a hardlink. The resulting filesystem will be the same, but now the first operation minidlna sees should be a full-fledged create, and therefore work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no workaround to my exact problem and unfortunately my setup doesn't allow reversing the minidlna share <> hardlink directory.

The only solution I found was to rebuild minidlna RPM with IN_CREATE in inotify.c (more details here - http://sourceforge.net/p/minidlna/bugs/227/)

Hopefully Readynas makes that the default for future builds.

Comment: The latest version of minidlna fixed my issue. v1.1.5 supports hardlinks.